# Solve nonlinear system of equations with minimal error

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I have some nonlinear optimization problem (preferably solved in python):

Given are 3 circles (centers x1..3,y1..3, radii d1..3) in a 2D plane.

```
(x-x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 - r1^2 = 0
(x-x2)^2 + (y-y2)^2 - r2^2 = 0
(x-x3)^2 + (y-y3)^2 - r3^2 = 0
```

The common point (x/y) is desired and can be computed by fsolve (scipy.optimize) in this case. **But how does one solve the problem if the radii r1..3 are with an uncertainness of u1..3**, respectively? I.e. the true radius of a circle is in the interval r-u ... r+u.

How can I find the optimal point (x/y) which incorportes the uncertainty of the radii?

Comment: This is 99% numerical analysis, 1% programming. I think you'll have better luck asking at the [math](http://www.math.stackexchange.com) site

Comment: What is the error function you are trying to minimize? What are the constants (x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,u?) and what are the parameters (r,x and y?) and what are the constraints (r-u<r1,r2,r3<r+u?)?

Comment: (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3) are the centers of the three circles with radii in the intervall r1+-u1, r2+-u2, r3+-u3. The smaller the unvertainty of a radius of a circle is the closer the desired point (x/y) should be to this circle.

Comment: even before you introduce the error, solution may not found.  you have to be real lucky so that three cicle coincide and share one point.  isnt it?

Comment: you then introduced uncertainty which make the circle to be a circle of band.  Now it is more likely that those three bands intersect with triangle-like rounded shape.  how do you know which point within these intersection you think better?

Comment: Exactly! I want to weighting the circels. Say the one with a smaller band (which means a smaller u) is more accurate. Whereas a circle with a large band is less precise. So the true point is positioned more close to the circle with the smaller band.

Comment: Put weights in your error function?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not so hard given the decription here:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

A proposed algorithm:

1. Find x - as described in the link.
2. Calculate y.

Both should be done using any 2 circles.

1. Plug the points (x,y) and (x,-y) in the 3 circle.
2. The solution is either that all three circles intersect at:
   x,y
   x,-y
   or not at all.

Another suggestion ...
I read again your question, and realized you're not looking to find
the point it self...

However, if you draw all 9 circles on a paper (the 3 intersecting, plus 2 smaller and larger for r+e and r-e, where e is error), you notice the following. Your intersection point lies within a polygon. You
can easily calculate the vertices of this polygon. And then your problem becomes either:
find a point in polygon. 
Or you write an objection function that finds these vertices, and then
you minimize that area.

To see what I mean about the circles, run:

```
# excuse me for the ugly code ...
import pylab
pylab.axes()

cir = pylab.Circle((1,0), radius=1, alpha =.2, fc='b')
cir1 = pylab.Circle((1,0), radius=0.9, alpha =.2, fc='b')
cir2 = pylab.Circle((1,0), radius=1.1, alpha =.2, fc='b')
cir3 = pylab.Circle((-1,0), radius=1, alpha =.2, fc='b')
cir4 = pylab.Circle((-1,0), radius=0.9, alpha =.2, fc='b')
cir5 = pylab.Circle((-1,0), radius=1.1, alpha =.2, fc='b')
cir6 = pylab.Circle((0,-1), radius=0.9, alpha =.2, fc='b')
cir7 = pylab.Circle((0,-1), radius=1.1, alpha =.2, fc='b')
cir8 = pylab.Circle((0,-1), radius=1, alpha =.2, fc='b')
pylab.gca().add_patch(cir)
pylab.gca().add_patch(cir1)
pylab.gca().add_patch(cir2)
pylab.gca().add_patch(cir3)
pylab.gca().add_patch(cir4)
pylab.gca().add_patch(cir5)
pylab.gca().add_patch(cir6)
pylab.gca().add_patch(cir7)
pylab.gca().add_patch(cir8)

pylab.axis('scaled')
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this way.   For a given point, p,  I calculate distance from the point to each of three circles.  This can be done by taking absolute value of difference between (1)distance between the point and the origin of a circle and (2) radius of the circle.  Then your objective function is to minimize the sum of three distances (p to circleA, p to circle B, p to circle C).  I'd try arithmetic sum, but there may be some good reason to aggregate differently (ensamble average kind of math).  YOu then use the nonlinear package to minimize the objective function (i.e. sum of three distance).

Now you have weight for each circle.  So you modify the objective function to discount the distance by uncertainty of each circle.  Again, you need some logic how this weigting is accomplished...  Naive method is to use "weighted average", which is to take 1/sigma^2 as weight for each distance.  so your objective function becomes

```
(weighted average distance) 
= ( distA * sigmaA^-2 + distB * sigmaB^-2 + distC * sigmaC^-2 ) 
   / ( sigmaA^-2 + sigmaB^-2 + sigmaC^-2)
```

where distX is distance from point to circle, sigmaA is standard deviation of location of the circle (due to uncertainty of cicle location and size), `^-2` denotes square and then divide.

Use nonlin package to minimize the above obj. function by changing x and y of the point.